# Dice rolling fight system

Tags: java, android

I am doing something like this:
When you clicked the button it will roll a dice in 1-6 and it will extract it from your opponet's hp.I write a code but it extratcs the number from the first hp of opponent.HP must be change in every roll, it must be less than starting hp.
Here is my code:

```
public static final Random RANDOM1 = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dosto = 20;
    düsmann = 20;
    dostt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dost);
    düsman = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rakip);
    saldir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
    saldirr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    dostt.setText(dosto + "");
    düsman.setText(düsmann + "");

    saldir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            randomD();
        }
    });
}

public void randomD() {

    int sayi = RANDOM1.nextInt(6) + 1;

    switch (sayi) {
        case 1:
            saldirr.setText(1 + " hasar");
            düsman.setText(düsmann-1 + "");
            break;
        case 2:
            saldirr.setText(2 + " hasar");
            düsman.setText(düsmann-2 + "");
            break;

        case 3:
            saldirr.setText(3 + " hasar");
                düsman.setText(düsmann-3 + "");
            break;

        case 4:
            saldirr.setText(4 + " hasar");
            düsman.setText(düsmann-4 + "");
            break;

        case 5:
            saldirr.setText(5 + " hasar");
                düsman.setText(düsmann-5 + "");
            break;

        case 6:
            saldirr.setText(6 + " hasar");
                düsman.setText(düsmann-6 + "");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i mean you rolled for first time and it is 1, it extratcs from 20 and says 19 but in next roll it extracts number from 20 again, not from 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to update your `düsmann` variable so do something like this for all your cases in the switch example for case 1:

```
case 1:
    düsmann = düsmann - 1;
    düsman.setText(düsmann);
    break;
```

Also to limit some code duplication you could use a method to do this

```
private void subtractFromDüsman(int sub){
   düsmann = düsmann - sub;
   düsman.setText(düsmann);
}
```

And call it from your cases

```
case 2 :
    subtractFromDüsman(2);
    break;
```

Comment: which switch should i write first part ?

Comment: now it looks like this and app stops when i clicked the button                                   case 1 :
                saldirr.setText(1+" hasar");
                düsmann -= 1;
                düsman.setText(düsmann);
                break;         trying again

Comment: i think i used once the wrong variable as düsmann and düsman are easy to mix up

Comment: it still stops when i clicked to button

Comment: @AlperGöktepe what stops?

Comment: app, it shutdowns itself

Comment: Thanks for help, i did it with adding every case this:   düsmann = düsmann -1;

Comment: @AlperGöktepe don't forget to adjust the number you use in each case to get your wanted functionality